# Xcode 6 if else statements getting an error of "Expected identifier or '('

Tags: ios, if-statement, xcode6

My goal is to create a person class with name and gender, set to my name and set the gender to 1 or 0 (1 for male or 0 for female). Then later be able to print out name and gender (i.e. Name: Chris and Gender:Male) therefore I need to change the 1 or 0 to male or female.  This is the first time I have ever attempted Xcode so I new and I am sorry if I am making a foolish mistake here.  I created my new class and have my Person.h and Person.m.

Person.h:

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    @interface Person : NSObject{
    NSString *Name;
    NSString *Gender;
    }
    @end
```

Person.m

```
    #import "Person.h"

    @implementation Person
    NSString *Name = @"John Snow";
    NSString *Gender =@"1";

    if (self.Gender = 1){
    NSString *Gender =@"Male";
    }
    else if (Gender = 0){
    NSString *Gender =@"Female";
    }
    else{
    NSString *Gender =@"Unknown";
    }@end
```

Everything appears to compile good until I add my if statements, all my if statement give me an error of "Expected identifier or '('. Maybe I am overthinking this and confusing myself even more,  I am not looking for someone to do my work for me, just a push in the right direction would be great.

Comment: You have to write the code inside some method. You can't just have code in the class definition itself.   Also your code makes no sense, since it is comparing a string as a int, the comparison is actually an assignment (= vs ==) and it is just assigning to (what would be) a local variable.

Comment: Watch the assignments ... should read 'if (self.gender == 1)' instead.  Also, inside you else blocks lose the pointer on the variables .... should read 'gender = @"Male"' instead.

Comment: It is probably better to define a Boolean `isMale` (or isFemale if you prefer)

Answer (score 0):

`Person.h` should be:

```
#import "Person.h"

    @implementation Person
    NSString *Name = @"John Snow";
    NSString *Gender =@"1";

    if (self.Gender == 1){
    NSString *Gender =@"Male";
    }
    else if (Gender == 0){
    NSString *Gender =@"Female";
    }
    else{
    NSString *Gender =@"Unknown";
    }@end
```

Comment: Thank you eMdOs, but that did not fix my issue, apparently I have dug a deep hole for myself.